# HTML elements have reduced sizes when using Apache and Firefox

Tags: php, html, css, apache, firefox

I was working on a personal test website, when I saw than Firefox outputs smaller elements than I asked when I opened the file passing trough Apache (`localhost/index.php` for example).

A simple `<div style="height:100px">test</div>` displays a box with a height of 91.5522 ...

However Chrome is displaying good sizes in both cases

I tried with both XAMPP and MAMP, same result

Here is an example :
(left is with Apache, right is direct path)

[image: left : Apache, smaller | right : direct path, normal size]

Comment: Are you sure the browser isn't zoomed in? Try hitting ctrl+0.

Comment: eithe it seems browser is zoomed in (hit ctrl+0) are some common css applied somewhere in css file(try to check css in browser debugger)

Comment: @Michael Coker Oh yes, i haven't checked that ! Thanks !
But now I'm wondering why Firefox opened a new window zoomed out (90%)

Comment: Firefox remembers the zoom factor by URL. This can be changed, by the way, with the about:config setting **browser.zoom.siteSpecific**